# history.push() from Action Creator will Change URL but will Not Navigate to Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, browser-history

I have a login page component and I would like to redirect, after a successful login, from the action creator (thunk).
It seem to work but while the URL changes correctly the page remains on the Login page.

here I import the history to be imported in the action creator:

```js
// helpers/history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default history;
```

here  the shorten version of the action creator:

```js
// actions/session.js
import history from '../helpers/history';


export const login = (formData) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: LOGIN_REQUEST})
        return fetch("http://localhost:3001/login", {
...
       .then((user) => {
            history.push('/live-rewards')
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
...
```

and here the shorten version of the component to show how login is called and the imports

```js
// containers/LoginForm.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { login } from '../actions/session'

class LoginForm extends Component {
...

    fetchOnSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      this.props.login(this.state)
    }
...
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    login: (credentials) => {
      return dispatch(login(credentials))
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

here instead how browserRouter is implemented:

```js
// index.js
...
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
...
```

```js
// app.js
...
    <Router>
      <Navbar toggle={toggle} />
      <Sidebar isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/live-rewards' component={Liverewards}/>
        <Route path='/signin' component={Signin}/>
        <Route path='/signup' component={Signup}/>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you ditch this `history` object entirely and handle your navigation from components which are inside of your `BrowserRouter` context rather than through an action creator.

`LoginForm` can access a contextual `history` prop through [`withRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter).  It can access the credentials in the state as pass an `isLoggedIn` prop through `mapStateToProps`.

The `render()` method of your `LoginForm` would include a `Redirect` component that is rendered conditionally depending on the `isLoggedIn` prop, which will update when you `dispatch` `LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS`.

---

Somehow map from `state` to a `boolean` prop `isLoggedIn`.  An example:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isLoggedIn: !!state.credentials.token
})
```

Conditional render:

```
{this.props.isLoggedIn && <Redirect to="/live-rewards" />}
```

---

I prefer this approach because it means that the log in page cannot be loaded at all if the user is already logged in.